# Notifications not working in web extension (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, firefox, notifications, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am using the Developer Version of Firefox (Version 54.0a2, but also tried the normal Firefox with Version 51) and I want to include notifications in my web extension.

browser["notifications"] does not exist though.

Since it was not working in my extension and I thought maybe something was conflicting I created this very basic web-extension.

the manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension",
  "version": "1.0",

  "description": "...",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
      ],
      "js": ["test.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["notifications", "storage"]
}
```

test.js (storage works just fine btw.)

```
if (browser["notifications"]) {
    console.log('Notifications exist!');

    browser.notifications.create({
      "type": "basic",
      "iconUrl": browser.extension.getURL("icons/icon-48.png"),
      "title": "test",
      "message": "test"
    });
  }
  else {
    //it always executes this part :/
    console.log('notifications do not exist');
    console.log(browser);
  }
```

Debugging the add-on doesn´t show any errors either.

Comment: I think you need to create the notification in background script. There is a simple example here : https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n

Comment: Thank´s, it works now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many of the apis exclusive for extensions can only be run inside background script. The usual technique if you need to run it from a content script is to send a message from content script to background script, handle the message in background script and run from there the command you wanted.

In your case, there are a few examples at the end of [Notification Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications), one of them being [notify-link-clicks-i18n](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/tree/master/notify-link-clicks-i18n) where you can view how they do the message passing to create the notification from the background script.